# Joining two tables in SQL in which one column has to be "cleaned"

Tags: sql

I need to join two tables in SQL, which has two related columns (column ID1 in Table 1 and column ID in Table 2). ID1 in table 1 consists of 6 digits, whereas ID2 in table 2 consists of 6 digitis but an additional quotation marks (") in the beginning and end of the string. I need to remove these quotation marks and join the two tables to verify if there is any values reocurring in both columns.

I know how to remove first and last character of the string in table 2:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING ([ID2],2,Len([ID2])-2) FROM [dbo].[table2]
```

I need to join this new "trimmed" column with the other column from table 1.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Additionaly, I have one "Names" column in each table. "Names" in Table 1 is fine, however names in Table 2 includes aliases as well. E.g." Freddy Johnson Alias: Freddy"

I only need the first name and the surname, thus I need a syntax that extracts the everything before Alias. Could use some help here!

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS in the question.  (MSSQL, MYSQL, ORACLE, DB2, ...)  Performance will suffer but there's no problem with using functions in a JOIN clause.  So, for example SELECT ... FROM A JOIN B on A.ID1 = SUBSTRING(B.id2, len(b.id2) - 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using ms sql server db, and need everything from table1 and matched from table2 then:

```
sample:
table1  |  table2
[ID]    |  [ID]
547832  |  "547832"
```

```
-----------------------------
select table1.* , table2.*
from
db.tb1 table1
left join
db.tb2 table2
on
table1.[ID] = SUBSTRING([ID2],2,Len([ID2])-2) ;
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. To be more precise these are the names of the tables: [database].[dbo].[table1] and [database].[dbo].[table2]. The columns are [Product ID] in table1 and [ID] in table2. [ID] in Table 2 starts and ends with a hyphen (-) and I need to drop that in order to join it on the [Product ID] column in Table 1. For that I am using the syntax: SELECT SUBSTRING ([ID],2,Len([ID])-2) FROM [database].[dbo].[table1] AS MyTrimmed. Now I want to join that on [Product ID] from [database].[dbo].[table2]. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First extract your trimmed column with different name by using 'AS' and then you can join the tables.
Try like the below

syntax: SELECT Substring( columnname , positon, length) AS Newcolumnname FROM Tablename;

EX: SELECT Substring(customerName,1,5) AS Newstr from Customer
Joins Table2 ON customer.Newstr = Table2.name;

Answer (score 0):

I am using MS SQL, yes.

Thanks for the reply. However, why is it a left join and not an inner join here? Just curious.

So, essentially what I need to do is:

In the first table, I have around 10 columns, in the second table I have 5 columns. They all have different names, ID was just used as an example. Two of the columns from table 2 appears to have similar values as two of the columns from table 1 (one is an ID of 6 digits, the other is names). I want to remove the first and last character of the 6 digits in the ID column in table 2 and join that and the names column with ID and names from table 1. Hope it makes sense